# Web application as module of a Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web

I do have a Java web application which has several servlets, I want to turn it into an optional module of a Spring mvc application. Ideally I would like to add the module as a "dependency" to make it available and add the proper link in my primary UI.

Is there a popular way to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you call a *dependency*? What should it share with the spring application: the servlet context, some data, filters? Or should it just be *callable* from first one? You currently have 2 anwers that IMHO answer to different questions: yours is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The "dependency" would be just an optionaI feature. so I want, if possible, to pack it as a module instead of placing its htmls (I am using thymeleaf) inside the _view_ directory of the parent application. For now I am just interested to make the parent application wrap the small one with spring security and of course, be able to forward the user from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all projects to maven projects, then Servlet specific projects are modules specified in the overarching MVC parent project.

That way, at build time, all required Servlet projects are automatically built by maven whenever you build the parent... And you can optionally exclude Servlets at build time.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a normal java servlet project to spring mvc you would need to do the following

1) In your web.xml you would have to specify your dispatcher servlet with and the url pattern for which it would get invoked. Specify the servlet class as the dispatcher servlet class and servlet name as a custom name for this servlet

2) Create an xml file as servletname-servlet.xml

3) Convert your custom servlets to controllers by having them implement the Controller interface and specify then in the xml file created in the second step

4) Define the mapping of these controllers to the requests

5) Define a view resolver for the requests

6) Deploy

These are broadly the steps you would need to perform to convert your servlet project to Spring MVC

Comment: Hi @prashant, thanks for your comment. I could convert my normal web application into a Spring MVC project, but how would I integrate it as a module/dependency into the bigger Spring MVC project?

Comment: you could do the following                                                                               1) Convert your servlets to controllers as described above and specify the controllers in an xml file. The create a jar of the existing project, add it to the lib directory of the main project and import the xml file into the main dispatcher servlet file of the bigger spring mvc project.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your servlet container(*), you could try to put the small application in its own servlet context on same container: that means that it would be a totally independant web application.

Then you install in main application a special controller mapped to a full hierarchy that would act as a forwarding relay for the secondary application. Something like :

```
@Autowired
String extContext;

@RequestMapping("/optapt/app1/**")
public void relay(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    ServletContext ext = req.getServletContex().getContext(extContext);
    String extUrl = req.getServletPath();
    if (req.getPathInfo() != null) {
        extUrl += req.getPathInfo();
    }
    ext.getDispatcher(extUrl).forward(req, resp);
}
```

That way, provided you have a global proxy that fordibs external clients to access the second application, all security can be managed by the main, and the second will only receive forwarded request from the main.

If for any reason, you have no proxy to hide the servlet container, you will still (but only) have *security by obfuscation*, since the direct addresses to the secondary application will never be published, provided you consistently only write addresses relative to first application in links and form actions

(*) `ServletContext.getContext()` may return null for security reasons on some servlet containers.

Comment: Thanks @Serge Ballesta, seems very promising. I have two doubts: I am using Tomcat, how can I have _a global proxy that forbids external clients to access the second application_? and  I assume `extContext` must contain something related to the context of the optional app but... what exactly?

Comment: The proxy is not Tomcat. It a a common usage to use a Apache or Jetty proxy in front of the Tomcat, because they are admitted to be more secure, allow load dispatching over several Tomcats, and can do basic URL security such as never allow access to the `/manager` on the Tomcat server. For `extContext` it contains the context path that means where the application is installed on the Tomcat.